# cygwin compiled tree successfully but no output

Tags: c++, compilation, tree, cygwin

Trying to compile `tree` from here (i uncommented appropriate section for cygwin in make script):

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

```
 $ make
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o tree.o tree.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o unix.o unix.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o html.o html.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o xml.o xml.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o hash.o hash.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o color.o color.c
 gcc -O2 -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -DCYGWIN -c -o strverscmp.o strverscmp.c
 gcc -s -o tree.exe tree.o unix.o html.o xml.o hash.o color.o strverscmp.o

 $ make install
 install -d /usr/bin
 install -d /usr/man/man1
 if [ -e tree.exe ]; then \
         install -s tree.exe /usr/bin/tree.exe; \
 fi
 install doc/tree.1 /usr/man/man1/tree.1
```

When i try to run however *crickets*

No output, no error, nothing. I'm using this compiler (running on 64bit cygwin):

```
 /usr/bin/gcc -> i686-pc-cygwin-gcc.exe
```

What am i doing wrong, how can i resolve?

EDIT:

More on *crickets*:

i checked return code (echo $?) and it's 127

However, i also did

```
 $ ls /usr/bin | grep tree
 tree.exe
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by _crickets_ ?  Does it hang? Return immediately without printing anything?  How about a copy of your shell session invoking it...

Comment: ps: if you just need a working tree, then get it from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html

Comment: @thebjorn i may get it from there, but now im curious why it's not behaving via compile :)

Comment: I have the same problem.  On Windows 7, cygwin `x86_64`, using `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc -v -o foo32.exe foo.c`, `./foo32` gives no output and exit code 127.  Foo.c is `#include <stdio.h>` and `void main(void){printf("%d",sizeof(int));}`.  Using straight gcc (64-bit), it prints out `4`.  Any thoughts?  @Nik, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I have same environment as you and no, I never did, my guess is it's missing a library or a resource from somewhere... I posted a comment on a related question, we'll see if we get something http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064317/installing-tree-1-6-0-in-cygwin-what-am-i-missing

Comment: I tried to compile with mingw32, im missing pwd.h and grp.h, when i compile with i686-pc-cygwin-gcc it compiles without errors but program doesnt work in cygwin :( ... i think u need to use the right toolchain with the right headers, it should work, i tried to copy the headers from i686-pc-cygwin-gcc sysroot to mingw, but it doesnt work, maybe someone knows the right combination will come along and enlighten us